# UIPageViewController in SplitView Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I want to have UIPageViewController in my Split view controller. So i have created UIPageViewController and replaced my detail view controller.

But now the problem is i can move to next pages but not previous pages. As i am using split view in portrait mode the master vc appears when i attempt to move to previous page. In landscape mode there is no response.

Any solution or sample would be appreciated.

I have followed this link to create UIPageViewCntroller 
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

Thanks in advcance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked as follows,

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

Now my master view will be visible always in Portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the swipe in the split view controller by doing

```
splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;
```

Comment: can u tell which delegate method will be called when i swipe to load the master view controller

Comment: it calls - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. In portrait mode, I have a graph in the detail view which I needed to drag around. I was having problems cause the master view would come up each time I dragged the graph to the right. Switching this flag to NO fixed that problem.